# Apache can't start because httpd is listening on port 80?

Tags: web-server, httpd, apache2, nextcloud

Hello serverfault community.
I'm setting up a nextcloud server, but apache is not starting.
When I run `systemctl status apache2` I get:

> ● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-02-03 12:13:29 CET; 2min 19s ago
> Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
> Process: 16936 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> feb 03 12:13:29 alumno-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP
> Server... feb 03 12:13:29 alumno-VirtualBox apachectl[16949]:
> (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to
> address [::]:80 feb 03 12:13:29 alumno-VirtualBox apachectl[16949]:
> (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to
> address 0.0.0.0:80 feb 03 12:13:29 alumno-VirtualBox apachectl[16949]:
> no listening sockets available, shutting down feb 03 12:13:29
> alumno-VirtualBox apachectl[16949]: AH00015: Unable to open logs feb
> 03 12:13:29 alumno-VirtualBox apachectl[16936]: Action 'start' failed.
> feb 03 12:13:29 alumno-VirtualBox apachectl[16936]: The Apache error
> log may have more information. feb 03 12:13:29 alumno-VirtualBox
> systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited,
> status=1/FAILURE feb 03 12:13:29 alumno-VirtualBox systemd[1]:
> apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. feb 03 12:13:29
> alumno-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.

I believe these would be the errors:

> (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to
> address [::]:80
>
> (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to
> address 0.0.0.0:80

When I run `sudo netstat -ltnp | grep :80` I get:

> tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                   LISTEN      3213/httpd

As seen here httpd is running on tcp6, and I think this could be a potential problem. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance and let me know if you need additional information.

Edit: The problem is solved but I did nothing to solve it. Sorry if this doesn't help but I really don't know how any of this happened

Comment: Where did "httpd" come from? How did it get onto your system?

Comment: I don't know but I wanted to know as well. Is there any way I could check?

Comment: I would find whoever installed the system and ask them what they did, if they are still employed by your company. Otherwise you could poke around the system yourself to see if you can figure out how it was installed. Try checking the package manager's history and possibly the root user's shell history.

Comment: When you had this issue, was it intermittent or consistent?

Answer (score 0):

I think httpd.service is for CentOS what apache2.service is for Debian based. Basically it's the same under different names. I advise you to check if httpd.service is really present with

```
 systemctl status httpd.service
```

If the result is positive, you can deactivate it

Comment: It says it could not be found which also confuses me